# Show that the component in $X$ of $a$, $C_X(a)$, is closed.

Tags: general-topology

> Show that the component in $X$ of $a$, $C_X(a)$, is closed.

The definition I know is $C_X(a)$ consist of all connected set, which consist of $a$. I have no idea on how to utilize the "clopen set definition" of connected set. Please halp.

Comment: Do you know that if $ A $ is connected and $ A\subseteq B\subseteq\overline A$, then $B$ is connected? That could be very helpful.

Comment: Yeah, I know this fact, can you explain more please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So $C_X(a) = \cup \{C \subset X: a \in C, C \text{ connected}\}$.

$C_X(a)$ is connected, as it is a union of connected subsets that all intersect in a common part (at least $\{a\}$).

The closure of a connected set is connected, so $K = \overline{C_X(a)}$ is (closed and) connected, and contains $a$, so $K$ is one of the sets we take a union of in the above definition of $C_X(a)$, which implies that $K \subset C_X(a)$, and the other inclusion is true as well, as a set if a subset of its closure. So $C_X(a) = K$, and the component of $a$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

As Stefan comments: if $A$ is connected and $A\subseteq B\subseteq\overline{A}$
then $B$ is connected.

An evident corollary is that connectedness
of $A$ implies connectedness of $\overline{A}$

Now take $A=C_{X}\left(a\right)$ here. Then - because it is a component - $A$ is connected hence so is $\overline{A}$.

Every connected set is the subset of some component so some component $D$ must exist with $A\subseteq\overline{A}\subseteq D$.

Here
$A\cap D\neq\emptyset$ (the set contains element $a$) and both sets are components.

Consequently $A=D$, since the components form a partition.

Then $A\subseteq\overline{A}\subseteq A$
so $A=\overline{A}$, or equivalently $A$ is closed.